# contentexporter FBX->SDKMESH warning and bad output

Tags: animation, directx, fbx

I am using the directxtk [contentexporter](https://github.com/walbourn/contentexporter) to convert a a fbx file with animation to sdkmesh. The fbx file is exported from blender, it includes an animation using model bones. After exporting to fbx, I can load the fbx file using autodesk fbx review and the animation displays correctly. When using contentexporter to convert the fbx to sdkmesh I get the following warning "No model binding for mesh "..." so creating a default subset". When trying to load the sdkmesh in the [directxtk model viewer](https://github.com/walbourn/directxtkmodelviewer) I get an error "Error loading model ...sdkmesh".

Answer (score 1):

The DirectX Tool Kit ContentExporter tool does not support skinned FBX models, in other words models containing skeletal animation.

You will need the FBX SDK or Assimp in your workflow pipeline to support skinned FBX animation in a DirectX app.

After a month or more of trial and error I was able to support FBX animation in a DirectX 12 game project, using just Blender and the FBX SDK.

For all static models, however, I'm also using ContentExporter to convert unskinned FBX models to SDKMESH format.

Textures are loaded separately in DirectX 12 and are bound to shaders via shader resource view (SRV) descriptor heaps.